# How to overcome error message about large package zip file and invoke function on Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am writing tests on Python and execute using Selenium with AWS Lambda. On last step uploaded zip package on S3 and attached link on this file in settings of Lambda, however when trying to save changes Lambda saying:

"The deployment package of your Lambda function "deployWebScraperLambdaSelenium" **is too large to enable inline code editing. However, you can still invoke your function right now.**"

Screenshot of settings in this link:
https://prnt.sc/k4e4u8

**buildn.zip file size ~58mb**

How possible to overcome this message and run Lambda test?

Answer (score 1):

The message about file size being too large is not an error message.

It is just telling you that because the file size is too large online editing of code is not allowed. However you can still go ahead and test the Lambda.

For that, click on 'Test' button at the top of the screen. Then select 'Create new test event'. Now give it a name and enter the  payload and hit Create. Now from the drop-down of available test events select the newly created test event and hit Test button. That should let you test your Lambda with your sample payload

Comment: Error message comes up After clicking on Test [screenshot on error](https://photos.app.goo.gl/phU9gUar4hrw528K6)

the file lambda_function.py located in root of zip file and inside this file method lambda_handler

Permission on reading/writing/executing checked

Why possible this errors comes up?